# How to calculate the size of the goldcap in energy harvesting?

Tags: nfc, energy-harvesting

I want to build an NFC-transponder (NFC chip: [ST25DV](https://www.st.com/en/nfc/st25dv04kc.html)) which is powered over energy harvesting. How could I calculate the size of the goldcap (supercapacitor) or maybe a normal tantalum capacitor to buffer the power?
I need:

- Standby current: 20 uA
- Peak current 20 mA for 10ms every minute

Comment: 20mA (0.02 A) times 10ms (0.01 s) divided by however much voltage you're allowed to lose during the sending

Comment: That sounds like 200 uF to me @user253751

Comment: well, that's if the allowable voltage drop is 1 volt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the NFC energy transfer is only sufficient to "hold-up" the capacitor voltage when the ST25 is drawing standby current, the only calculation to be made is when the ST25 is taking 20 mA for 10 ms. You then need to figure out how much voltage droop can be tolerated when the ST25 is taking 20 mA. Let's make an assumption that it is 0.5 volts. Calculating the necessary capacitance is based on this well known formula: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

Reverse this to find capacitance and, for the figures given, it needs to be 400 μF. Of course, if the voltage droop can be greater then capacitance can be smaller. The data sheet for the ST25 should tell you what the maximum charge voltage limit is and, it should also tell you how low this can droop before you get chip malfunction.

If the NFC energy transfer is significant, it may be able to partially charge the capacitor during the heavier load scenario and, that means the capacitor can be smaller also. I suggest using a simulator to set-up a simple circuit experiment where you can adjust the NFC charging current.